# Ａ problem concerning ordering issue using sort_vlue(pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I want to find out a max value, so I use `df.groupby('h_type').max()['h_price']`  but it gives a strange result.  Therefore, I use the following code and then find out there is an ordering issue

```py
bond=pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/test/datahistory/c.csv',index_col='h_type')
a=bond.loc['mansion']
aMax=a.sort_values(['h_price'],ascending=False)
aMax
```

**Then it yields:**

[image]

What kind of the problem may it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is column `h_price` is not numeric, need:

```
bond=pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/test/datahistory/c.csv',index_col='h_type')
bond['h_price'] = bond['h_price'].str.replace(',','.', regex=True).astype(float)

a=bond.loc['mansion']
aMax=a.sort_values(['h_price'],ascending=False)
```